# Scrape Highcharts data to CSV file

Tags: python, highcharts, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I want to scrape historical data of specific coins from the [CoinMarketCap website](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/verge/) using Python. I want as granular data as possible. I think the data comes from the following string :

[image: Chart with source code]

I want to use BeautifulSoup to get this data and save it to a CSV file, but I have no clue how.

Comment: Take a look at https://journalistsresource.org/tip-sheets/research/python-scrape-website-data-criminal-justice it should give you an idea of things you'll need.

Comment: using `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox (tab Network->XHR) I see JavaScript read some data as JSON from `https://graphs.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/verge/` - maybe it is what you need.

Comment: BTW: if page uses JavaScript to add element on page(and most pages do it) then `BeautifulSoup` can be useless because `reuqests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. And then you may have to use `Selenium` to control web browser which will open page and run JavaScript. Or you may try different method: mostly JavaScript reads data from some url so you can try to find this url using `DevToool`

Answer (score 4):

It seems it uses JavaScript which use url

```
https://graphs.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/verge/1513624444000/1514229244000/
```

to get data as JOSN so you can easily get it as python dictionary

**EDIT:** it uses `timestamp*1000` in url to get historical data. And it write in `csv`

```
import requests
import datetime
import csv

date1 = '2016.01.01'
date2 = '2017.01.01'

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y.%m.%d')
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y.%m.%d')

date1 = int(date1.timestamp() * 1000)
date2 = int(date2.timestamp() * 1000)

print('dates:', date1, date2)
print('-----')

url = 'https://graphs.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/verge/{}/{}/'.format(date1, date2)

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

for key in data.keys():
    print('key:', key)
print('-----')

f = open('output.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

row = ('date', 'price_btc', 'price_usd', 'volume_usd')
csv_writer.writerow(row)

for item1, item2, item3 in zip(data['price_btc'], data['price_usd'], data['volume_usd']): #[:10]:

    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item1[0]//1000)
    date = date.strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')

    print('date:', date)
    print(' btc:', item1[1])
    print(' usd:', item2[1])
    print(' vol:', item3[1])
    print('-----')

    row = (date, item1[1], item3[1], item3[1])
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

f.close()
```

Part of result:

```
dates: 1451602800000 1483225200000
-----
key: market_cap_by_available_supply
key: price_btc
key: price_usd
key: volume_usd
-----
date: 2016.01.01 00:04:19
 btc: 3.00032e-08
 usd: 1.29262e-05
 vol: 548
-----
date: 2016.01.02 00:04:19
 btc: 2.1964e-08
 usd: 9.52678e-06
 vol: 246
-----
date: 2016.01.03 00:04:19
 btc: 2.67174e-08
 usd: 1.15926e-05
 vol: 2805
-----
```

---

**EDIT:** read in loop

```
import requests
import datetime
import csv
import webbrowser


def get_data(name, timestamp1, timestamp2, csv_writer):

    url = 'https://graphs.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{}/{}/{}/'.format(name, timestamp1, timestamp2)

    response = requests.get(url)

    try:
        data = response.json()
    except Exception:
        with open('output.html', 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.text)
        webbrowser.open('output.html')
        exit()

    for item1, item2, item3 in zip(data['price_btc'], data['price_usd'], data['volume_usd']): #[:10]:

        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item1[0]//1000)
        date = date.strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')

        row = (date, item1[1], item3[1], item3[1])
        csv_writer.writerow(row)


def scrape(name, start_date, finish_date):

    f = open(name + '.csv', 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

    row = ('date', 'price_btc', 'price_usd', 'volume_usd')
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

    one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y.%m.%d')
    finish_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(finish_date, '%Y.%m.%d')

    date1 = start_date
    date2 = start_date + one_day

    while date1 < finish_date:
        print(name, date1, date2)

        date1_timestamp = int(date1.timestamp() * 1000)
        date2_timestamp = int(date2.timestamp() * 1000)

        get_data(name, date1_timestamp, date2_timestamp, csv_writer)

        date1 = date2
        date2 += one_day

    f.close()    

# --- main ---

scrape('verge', '2016.01.01', '2017.01.01')
scrape('bitcoin', '2016.01.01', '2017.01.01')
scrape('ethereum', '2016.01.01', '2017.01.01')
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Do you know how I could get it into a csv ?

Comment: python has module `csv` to write in `CSV` or you can use `pandas` to create `DataFrame` and then use `to_csv()`.

Comment: Also, it seems that I don't get ALL the data (only part of it). Would you know how to get all the historical data points ? THANKS A MILLION

Comment: see `/1513624444000/1514229244000/` in url - it is date as timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: see new code which gets data in range `'2016.01.01', '2017.01.01'` and it saves in `csv` file in columns `'date', 'price_btc', 'price_usd', 'volume_usd'`

Comment: Indeed !  I'm realising that the closer those timestamps were together, the more granular the data were. I get the higher granularity with a delta of 1 day between the initial and the final milliseconds count. If you were to do have 3 variable (initial date, final date, and the coin name ... here the verge) and do a loop for each 1 day increment and write them in a csv file, how would you do it ?

Comment: I would put all in `for` loop and change only dates

Comment: Is there a way to do at the end of the same csv file ?

Comment: By the way, thank you again SO MUCH for your help so far. I honestly got stuck on this for hours and you just solved it in a couple of minutes. THANK YOU

Comment: you can `reversed()` lists with data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this

Comment: sorry I thought you want the newest prices at the beginning. Current code write all in one file. If you need to add to existing file when you start script next time then you can write in append mode `a` or `a+` instead of `w`

Comment: I add code which read many different coins but I couldn't test it because I'm temporally banned by this portal - too many requests from one IP. You may have to search information how to use proxy servers.

Comment: BTW: this page has some API but not all is available in this API: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

Comment: Thanks a million. Indeed I was aware of the API, but it was too poor in granularity of data. It worked for a while, but now I'm getting a weird error (line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0))

Comment: Still the same issue, I am not sure I understand why this happened ?    
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: you are banned - and it send warning message instead of JSON data.

Comment: How would you bypass this ? Just wait ? Or maybe put lag time in the code ?

Comment: as I wrote before you may try to find imforamtion how to use proxy servers and then you will have different IP.

Comment: Hmmm ... I really don't want to be the brat that keeps asking questions, but how would you implement that in the code ?

Comment: see example in requests doc: [proxy](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies). But problem can be to find free proxy servers which work stably. If you use `Tor` then you can try to use it as proxy - [Using python requests over Tor](https://techoverflow.net/2015/02/06/using-python-requests-over-tor/)

Comment: Hi Furas ! I’ve been thinking a lot about that problem lately. And I am wondering, as we are basically hitting the request for the same page, isn’t there a way to (i) download first all the pages for the coins of interest (e.g., https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/verge/)  (ii) do the request locally for the downloaded pages (so do all the request on the file for the /verge stored locally on my machine) ?

Comment: you rather means to save all in local files and read from files. To request locally you would need local web server - and it makes no sense if you can save/read files without local web server.

Comment: Yes, I meant reading from files. How could I do that ? Happy New Years !

Comment: in `scrape` in last code you have code which saves in csv file. You have to only check if you request the same url and skip it and read data from file - you would have to create list with visited urls to check if you visit url again. Or you can check if you already have file for visited url and then you don't have to request this url.

Comment: Hmmmmm ... I see. But then how do you make sure we have timestamps close enough so we have as granular data as before (and then consolidate) ? Because here we have only data, while we would ideally like as granular data as possible (5 min spaced). THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP AGAIN